# EJB3 based Webservice Endpoint generated with an actual bean name

Tags: web-services, jboss, cxf

I am converting an existing Webservice endpoint from WebSphere(8) to Jboss (EAP 6.3).
My endpoint is created as EJB3 bean and looks like that :
    package com.company.project.ridethecar.ejb;

```
@WebService(
    endpointInterface ="com.company.schemas.project.srm.ridethecarservice.soap_service.v1.RideTheCarSer vicePortType", 
    targetNamespace ="http://schemas.company.com/project/srm/ridethecarservice/soap-service/v1",
    serviceName = "RideTheCarService", 
    portName = "RideTheCarServiceSoap", 
    wsdlLocation = "META-INF/wsdl/RideTheCarService/v2.00/RideTheCarService.wsdl") 
@Stateless(name="RideTheCarBean")
    @Local({com.company.schemas.project.srm.ridethecarservice.soap_service.v1.RideTheCarServicePortType.class})
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
@Service
@HandlerChain(file="/RideTheCar-handler-chain.xml")
public class RideTheCarBean implements RideTheCarServicePortType
{...}
```

I also have WSDL defined for the webService and I am using CXF maven cxf-codegen-plugin (version 3.1.7) to generate java beans.  My RideTheCarServicePortType will be generated as following :

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://schemas.company.com/project/srm/ridethecarservice/soap-service/v1", name = "RideTheCarServicePortType")
@XmlSeeAlso({com.comapny.schemas.project.messaging.v1.ObjectFactory.class, com.company.schemas.project.srm.ridethecarservice.service.v1.ObjectFactory.class    })
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface RideTheCarServicePortType {

    @WebMethod(action = "http://schemas.company.com/project/srm/ridethecarservice/soap-service/v1/EnvRideTheCarService")
    @Action(input = "http://schemas.company.com/project/srm/ridethecarservice/soap-service/v1/RideValidationRq", output = "http://schemas.company.com/project/srm/ridethecarservice/soap-service/v1/RideValidationRs")
    @WebResult(name = "PbaValidationRs", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.company.com/project/srm/ridethecarservice/service/v1", partName = "RideValidationRs")
public com.company.schemas.project.srm.ridethecarservice.service.v1.RideValidationRs rideValidation(
    @WebParam(partName = "RideValidationRq", name = "RideValidationRq", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.company.com/project/srm/ridethecarservice/service/v1")
    com.company.schemas.project.srm.ridethecarservice.service.v1.RideValidationRq rideValidationRq
);

}
```

I am packaging all the code as a WAR file, using maven and deploying it into the 
JBoss. JBoss is able to identify EJB and Webservice, but unfortunately it automatically creates an endpoint as

http://localhost:8080/root/RideTheCarService/**RideTheCarBean**?wsdl. 
I would expect to see the http://localhost:8080/root/RideTheCarService?wsdl, without the RideTheCarBean part - as it was working like that in the WebSphere.

Could you please assist me with understanding, why Jboss is defining an endpoint using bean, instead of an actual Service name defined in the "servicename" attribute of the @Webservice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was pretty simple - Had to use jboss-webservices.xml file in the META-INF folder of the EJB package.

```
<context-root>/RideTheCarService</context-root>
<port-component>
    <ejb-name>RideTheCarBean</ejb-name>
    <port-component-name>RideTheCarSoap</port-component-name>
    <port-component-uri>/RideTheCar</port-component-uri>
</port-component>
```

This will ensure that RideTheCar URL will be exposed.